# Paypal ExpressCheckout: rounding problem

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal-express

tldr; According to magento fix notes the rounding error is fixed in 1.8 and later. We use 1.9 and have the rounding error for paypal express.
How to fix it?

---

In a new storeview I have an error with paypal Express Checkout.

```
#10413 The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
```

I could break it down (with debug mode) to a rounding problem. But I have also seen that some data is not passed to magento on the new storeview (address for example)

Here is the debug from the new storeview:

```
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
    [SetExpressCheckout] => Array
        (
            [PAYMENTACTION] => Authorization
            [AMT] => 97.80
            [CURRENCYCODE] => EUR
            [RETURNURL] => ...
            [CANCELURL] => ...
            [INVNUM] => 700000030
            [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Mark
            [GIROPAYCANCELURL] => ...
            [GIROPAYSUCCESSURL] => ...
            [BANKTXNPENDINGURL] => ...
            [LOCALECODE] => de_DE
            [ITEMAMT] => 75.55
            [TAXAMT] => 15.62
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 6.64
            [L_NUMBER0] => LE-PANEL595-40-CW
            [L_NAME0] => ...Itemname...
            [L_QTY0] => 1
            [L_AMT0] => 75.55
            [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-06-25T12:22:42Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => b9eeaea2f446
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 17159089
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        )

    [__pid] => 26085
)
```

and here the debug from the old storeview:

```
(
    [url] => https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
    [SetExpressCheckout] => Array
        (
            [PAYMENTACTION] => Authorization
            [AMT] => 107.80
            [CURRENCYCODE] => CHF
            [RETURNURL] => ...
            [CANCELURL] => ...
            [INVNUM] => 100000262
            [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Mark
            [GIROPAYCANCELURL] => ...
            [GIROPAYSUCCESSURL] => ...
            [BANKTXNPENDINGURL] => ...
            [LOCALECODE] => de_CH
            [ITEMAMT] => 92.50
            [TAXAMT] => 7.99
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 7.31
            [L_NUMBER0] => LE-PANEL595-40-CW
            [L_NAME0] => ...itemname...
            [L_QTY0] => 1
            [L_AMT0] => 92.50
            [BUSINESS] => 
            [NOTETEXT] => 
            [EMAIL] => asdf@asdf.com
            [FIRSTNAME] => asdf
            [LASTNAME] => asdf
            [MIDDLENAME] => 
            [SALUTATION] => 
            [SUFFIX] => 
            [COUNTRYCODE] => CH
            [STATE] => 
            [CITY] => asdf
            [STREET] => asdf
            [ZIP] => 1111
            [PHONENUM] => 11 111 111
            [SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] => CH
            [SHIPTOSTATE] => 
            [SHIPTOCITY] => asdf
            [SHIPTOSTREET] => asdf
            [SHIPTOZIP] => 1111
            [SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 11 111 111
            [SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
            [STREET2] => 
            [SHIPTONAME] => asdf asdf
            [ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
            [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Magento_Cart_Community
        )

    [response] => Array
        (
            [TOKEN] => EC-1TY898842U856944H
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-06-25T12:59:46Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => a456de03a7b81
            [ACK] => Success
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [BUILD] => 17159089
        )

    [__pid] => 27391
)
```

There are alot of infos that are missing in the new storeview. But the problem is the rounding

**Edit** I said the shipping cost are not passed to paypal in the new store view. Thats wrong, the shipping costs are there `[SHIPPINGAMT] => 6.64`.

It is a rounding problem: `[ITEMAMT] => 75.55` + `[TAXAMT] => 15.62` + `[SHIPPINGAMT] => 6.64` = 97.81, but `[AMT] => 97.80`. So that is the problem. I have read about some rounding problems in 1.7, but we use Magento Version 1.9.0.1. I will search for other similar problems now.

P.S. Our prices includes taxes.

Comment: still unsolved isn't it?

Comment: @Irkwz yes unsovled, but not my project anymore

Comment: And another fix is to force equivalency => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191209/paypal-api-the-totals-of-the-cart-item-amounts-do-not-match-order-amounts

Answer (score 3):

The only "safe" solution I've found consist in blocking Magento to send to Paypal the order items.

In the admin panel goto `System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods` then select `'Paypal payment solutions' > 'Website payments standard'` set `'Transfer Cart Line Items'` to `'no'`.

From now on Magento will tell paypal only the order total, shipment and taxes WITHOUT order details so paypal cannot make calculations anymore.

Comment: Sounds like a solution, sadly I cant test it anymore

Answer (score 1):

Change the taxes computation logic, it solved for me.

Check under: "System > Config > Sales > Taxes > Calculation Settings > Tax Calculation Method Based On"

Try using "Total" or "Row Total".

Answer (score 1):

This problem seems to be caused in Mage_Paypal_Model_Api_Abstract where _filterAmount is called. Magento uses round for rounding everywhere whilst sprintf is used for rounding here. When the 3rd decimal is a 5 this produces different results.

```
 sprintf('%.2F', 1.255);
```

This output 1.25 while

```
round(1.255,2);
```

outputs 1.26

changing `sprintf('%.2F', $value);`
to `round($value, 2);`
fixed the problem for me.