# PayPal Express rounding issue in Configurable Product (MCE 1.9.1.0 / 1.9.0.1)

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, paypal-express, rounding

PayPal Express creates a rounding issue error in Magento CE 1.9

Magento have confirmed this is a bug [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/710):  - but this bug was reported in April and still no confirmation from Magento if/when this will be fixed.

Can anyone help with a work-around?

Full steps with screenshots to recreate the bug are in the link http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/710

Thanks in advance

Comment: edited: added line breaks for readability

Answer (score 0):

See my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/102025/3515 for a workaround involving the ipn configuration (no coding)